# How do the splits in a decision tree classifier work?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I would like to know how the splits in the decision tree look like.

More specifically, I am wondering if they can be "relative". For example can the criterion be something like:

```
if x > y ..
```

or does it have to be some absolute value, as in:

```
if x > 0.5 ..
```

I don't know if it's worth creating synthetic features that introduce relationships between features or if that's already included per default.

Comment: Are we assuming that x and y are two features in the original data? If so: no. But it usually doesn't make sense to compare those, it would be like saying: "if a person's weight in kg is greater than their height in cm." i.e. the units do not make sense.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I see. But.. as you know, there is a famous training set with flowers. Why would something like "if the width of the petals is bigger than the length" not make sense?